# Google AdMob error after update to Xcode 11 Swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, admob, xcode11, swift5

Since I have updated to Xcode 11 the interstitial ads in my app won't load anymore. 
(Before that everything worked fine. The app was even released on the App Store. We are now creating an updated version of the app)

I installed the Google AdMobs SDK via Cocoapods and updated this to the latest version. Still no success. (I followed all the steps of Google's tutorial, how to implement interstitial ads)
These are the error messages I get from the console:

```
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.543249+0100 BuszZer[76592:876619] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.599222+0100 BuszZer[76592:876796] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.599426+0100 BuszZer[76592:876796] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.599610+0100 BuszZer[76592:876787] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.600170+0100 BuszZer[76592:876787] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.600215+0100 BuszZer[76592:876796] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.601185+0100 BuszZer[76592:876787] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.601435+0100 BuszZer[76592:876796] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.608414+0100 BuszZer[76592:876619] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000360a1a0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.610662+0100 BuszZer[76592:876789]  - <Google>[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), ca-app-pub-9056820091768756~5451481231
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.611337+0100 BuszZer[76592:876789]  - <Google>[I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60102000 started
    2019-10-10 21:42:35.611517+0100 BuszZer[76592:876789]  - <Google>[I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
```

Does anybody have similar problems or experiences and knows how to solve them? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have these errors in debug console of XCode 11.1 for my banner test ads from AdMob. Test ads are loading in simulator and device.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command in a terminal:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config \
   --mode "level:off" \
   --subsystem com.apple.CoreTelephony
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what this command does and how it helps address the question.